# How to integrate fan out DB structure with firebase

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase

I am trying to figure out how to integrate the fan out DB structure, [as seen here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html?m=1), in firebase.

I have an app which is like instagram. In order to create the kind of timeLine it seems I will have to do the following:

```
timeline/UID/UIDOFPersonWhoIsFollowed:randomNum/post/|//data
```

In this case the UID of the person who the user follows has to also include some kind of random number in order to make it always different.

**Is this correct?**

Also: If a user has 1 million followers, how will I be able to post to every one of those followers? I currently only have a spot where I store the people one user follows: Does this mean I will have to create a followers node which keeps track of whoFollows "me"?

with a follower structure like:

```
WhoFollowsMeNode/UID/uid: true
```

I would have to, every time a user posts, loop through this list where for each user I would add the post to there timeLine... That seems undoable, and [yet that what it seems they are doing here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html?m=1).

Comment: Is this correct? Depends. If you need to generate a random node key, .childByAutoId is your best friend. However, it depends on the use case - you may want to use the uid as the key with a value of true. There are a number of other solutions as well. The second question is well, another separate question and will depend on how you structure your Firebase for the first part of the question. I'll throw out an example structure in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often times you will want to keep track of who a user is following and also who is following that user. there is no singular answer as it depends on the use case, queries, etc.

There's really not enough information in the question as as to understand what the 'timeline' is or what kind of queries would be performed on the data so it's difficult to present a specific answer.

Here's one generic option for structuring a Firebase where users can know about each other.

As you can see there's no need to random node keys to handle the following aspect. Also, this is highly scalable as there could be thousands of users and thousands of follows and the amount of data in tiny as you're just storing users id's and a 'true' value, which is just a placeholder in this case.

```
users
   uid_0
      name: "Henry"
      followed_by:
         uid_1: true //followed by Leroy
         uid_2: true //followed by Amber
      following:
         uid_3: true //following Ralph
   uid_1
      name: "Leroy"
      followed_by:
         uid_2: true //followed by Amber
         uid_3: true //followed by Ralph
      following:
         uid_0: true //following Henry
   uid_2
      name: "Amber"
      followed_by:
         uid_3: true //followed by Ralph
      following:
         uid_0: true //following Henry
         uid_1: true //following Leroy
   uid_3
      name: "Ralph"
      followed_by:
         uid_0: true //followed by Henry
      following:
         uid_1: true //following Leroy
         uid_2: true //following Amber
```

This structure will allow each user to know who they are following and who is following them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer: Question: If I was instagram then whenever a user who has millions of followers creates a post, then I would have to loop through millions of uids and add to each uids timeline, either a duplicate of the post or a reference to where the post is located in the posts node. Wouldent this be unscalable? Firebases artical [https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html?m=1] Seems to adress this but upon reading it seems that they would be doing the exact thing I am proposing.

Comment: @NCT127 That depends on the use case. In my example, a user knows who they are following and who is following them. If a user doesn't care about who is following them then you would not need to add that reference. The idea of users following someone so they will be notified of any new posts comes down to the user that's following adding an observer to whoever they are following so when a new post occurs, they are notified about it. That eliminates looping; imagine if user a decides to follow user b. User a observers users b posts node and when a new post occurs, user a is notified